# How to install local python modules in subdirectories as separate packages from the root directory?

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I have a repo with this structure:

```
root_dir/
├── python/
│   └── libraries/
│       └──types/
│           ├── type1/
│           │   └── math/
│           │       └── math.py
│           └── type2/
│               └── categories/
│                   └── category1/ 
│                       ├── module1/
│                       │   └── module1.py
│                       ├── module2/
│                       │   ├──module2.py
│                       │   └── test/
│                       │       └── test_module2.py
│                       └── module3/
│                           ├── module3.py
│                           └── test/
│                               └── test_module3.py
└── notebooks/
    └── type1/
        └── categories/
            └── category1/
                └── notebook.ipynb
```

How can I install `root_dir\python\libraries\types\type1` as `types.type1` and `root_dir\python\libraries\types\type2\categories` as `types.type2.categories` from the root directory `root_dir`
as two separate packages? I want to be able to import these modules to `notebook.ipynb` using:

```
from types.type1.math.math import Vector
from types.type2.categories.category1.module1.module1 import Calculator
from types.type2.categories.category1.module2.module2 import Processor
```

Comment: What have you tried? -- You have the most chances of getting good answers if you can reduce your question to a full, standalone [mre]. -- Looks like you want [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/). -- Then I think there will be the difficulty of having two source trees in one. That is very tricky. It would make your life much easier if you could really split the two source trees. If you can not, then I would recommend using setuptools as build backend and work with its `package_dir` feature.

Comment: I tried creating a setup.py file in `root_dir\python\libraries` and a second one in `root_dir\python\libraries\types` which didn't work because I was using `find_packages` instead of `find_namespace_packages`. Changing to `find_namespace_packages` solved the issue, thanks @sinoroc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a setup.py file to root_dir\python\libraries like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    name='types.type1',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where='types', include=['type1.math']),
    package_dir={'': 'types'},
)
```

and a second setup.py file to root_dir\python\libraries\types like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    name='types.type2.categories',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where='type2'),
    package_dir={'': 'type2'},
    install_requires=[
        'types.type1',
    ]
)
```

has solved the problem. I can now use these import statements:

```
from type1.math.math import Vector
from categories.category1.module1.module1 import Calculator
from categories.category1.module2.module2 import Processor
```

which works fine for my project.